# Read text-file into program as dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, input

Using Python 3.

I have to write a function that take one argument (a string), and must return a dictionary from a txt-file that contains names of the sequences (keys) and the sequences (values). Both keys and values must be strings.

The text-file:

```
Read1 GGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTCGTCCAGACCCCTAGC
Read2 CTTTACCCGGAAGAGCGGGACGCTGCCCTGCGCGATTCCAGGCTCCCCACGGG
Read4 TGCGAGGGAAGTGAAGTATTTGACCCTTTACCCGGAAGAGCG
Read3 GTCTTCAGTAGAAAATTGTTTTTTTCTTCCAAGAGGTCGGAGTCGTGAACACATCAGT
Read5 CGATTCCAGGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTC
Read6 TGACAGTAGATCTCGTCCAGACCCCTAGCTGGTACGTCTTCAGTAGAAAATTGTTTTTTTCTTCCAAGAGGTCGGAGT
```

I've come this far, but I think I am missing something and I don't know if what my work here is correct. I've marked the lines (with #) where I'm in doubt whether it is correct or not.

```
def read_data(file_name):
    input_file=open(sequencing_reads.txt)
    #sequence_dict={}
    for line in input_file:
        #x=line.split(",")
    #return sequence_dict
    input_file.close()
```

I know it must return the dictionary with the following content:

```
{'Read1': 'GGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTCGTCCAGACCCCTAGC',
 'Read2': 'CTTTACCCGGAAGAGCGGGACGCTGCCCTGCGCGATTCCAGGCTCCCCACGGG',
 'Read4': 'TGCGAGGGAAGTGAAGTATTTGACCCTTTACCCGGAAGAGCG',
 'Read3': 'GTCTTCAGTAGAAAATTGTTTTTTTCTTCCAAGAGGTCGGAGTCGTGAACACATCAGT',
 'Read5': 'CGATTCCAGGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTC',
 'Read6': 'TGACAGTAGATCTCGTCCAGACCCCTAGCTGGTACGTCTTCAGTAGAAAATTGTTTTTTTCTTCCAAGAGGTCGGAGT'}
```

Can you help me fill out the gaps?

EDIT: I need to keep it simple so please no imports of packages and smart tricks :-)

EDIT 2:

I've tried this too:

```
with open('sequencing_reads.txt', 'r') as document:
    answer = {}
    for line in document:
        line = line.split()
        if not line:  
            continue
        answer[line[0]] = line[1:]
print(answer)
```

The output is:

```
{'Read1': ['GGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTCGTCCAGACCCCTAGC'], 'Read2': ['CTTTACCCGGAAGAGCGGGACGCTGCCCTGCGCGATTCCAGGCTCCCCACGGG'], 'Read4': ['TGCGAGGGAAGTGAAGTATTTGACCCTTTACCCGGAAGAGCG'], 'Read3': ['GTCTTCAGTAGAAAATTGTTTTTTTCTTCCAAGAGGTCGGAGTCGTGAACACATCAGT'], 'Read5': ['CGATTCCAGGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTC'], 'Read6': ['TGACAGTAGATCTCGTCCAGACCCCTAGCTGGTACGTCTTCAGTAGAAAATTGTTTTTTTCTTCCAAGAGGTCGGAGT']}
```

How do I get rid of the "[ ]" around my sequences?

EDIT4:

```
def read_data(file_name):
    with open("sequencing_reads.txt", "r") as document:
        answer = {}
        for line in document:
            line = line.split()
            if not line:
                continue
                answer[line[0]] = line[1:]
                final_answer = {a:b[0] for a, b in answer.items()}
final_answer = read_data("sequencing_reads.txt")
print(final_answer)
```

prints:

```
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re
def read_data(file_name):
   data = open(file_name).read()
   keys = [filter(lambda x:bool(x), i)[0][1:-1] for i in re.findall("{(.*?)\:|(?<=,\n\s)(.*?)\:", data)]
   values = [filter(lambda x:bool(x), i)[0][1:-1] for i in re.findall('(?<=:\s)(.*?)(?=,\n)|(?<=\s)(.*?)(?=})', data)]
   final_data = {a:b for a, b in zip(keys, values)}
   return final_data
```

Output:

```
{'Read1': 'GGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTCGTCCAGACCCCTAGC', 'Read3': 'GTCTTCAGTAGAAAATTGTTTTTTTCTTCCAAGAGGTCGGAGTCGTGAACACATCAGT', 'Read2': 'CTTTACCCGGAAGAGCGGGACGCTGCCCTGCGCGATTCCAGGCTCCCCACGGG', 'Read5': 'CGATTCCAGGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTC', 'Read4': 'TGCGAGGGAAGTGAAGTATTTGACCCTTTACCCGGAAGAGCG', 'Read6': "'Read6': 'TGACAGTAGATCTCGTCCAGACCCCTAGCTGGTACGTCTTCAGTAGAAAATTGTTTTTTTCTTCCAAGAGGTCGGAGT"}
```

Edit:

```
import ast 
def read_data(file_name):
   final_data = ast.literal_eval(open(file_name).read())
   return final_data
```

Edit 1: Regarding the removal of the brackets, just access the value by indexing:

```
final_answer = {a:b[0] for a, b in answer.items()}
print(final_answer)
```

If you are having issues printing the value returned from `read_data`, you can try this:

```
answer = read_data("the_file.txt")
print(answer)
```

Edit 3:

```
def read_data(file_name):
   with open(file_name, "r") as document:
      answer = {}
      for line in document:
         line = line.split()
         if line:
            answer[line[0]] = line[1:]
      return {a:b[0] for a, b in answer.items()}

print(read_data("sequencing_reads.txt"))
```

Comment: Thank you, but what do I have to write to get it printed? Seems like no matter what I print, I get some kind of error.
Also, the txt file already contains the names (read1,read2 ect), so basically I just want python to open the file as a dictionary

Comment: Gangsta python. It took a second to recognise the implicit context manager. It'd be fun to see this in a lambda.

Comment: @RicklePick Please see my recent edit. I altered my original answer as I realized that you posted the contents of the file, and not the desired output. Therefore, this solution should output what you need.

Comment: @Ajax1234 This is overkill. You open the file without closing it then you implement a json parser using regular expressions.

Comment: @everyone In this case, the file does not need to be closed after calling `open('file.txt')` because Python closes it automatically. Regarding a json parser, there is no guarantee that the file's contents has been formatting to json

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately I don't understand exactly what you are doing and for my own sake I need to keep it as simple as possible, hence I really just need to know what I'm doing wrong and what I am missing in my first post. I really appreciate your help hopefully one day I will be able to do and understand your way of solving this :)

Comment: @Ajax1234 It is implementation dependent whether the interpreter closes the file or not so it's not good practice.

Comment: @RicklePick I apologize, I just posted a much shorter solution.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Thank you. Much more understandable to me now

Comment: @Ajax1234 one last question. What do I write to get the output printed? I get a NameError when I try to print this, as it says whatever I'm trying to print, isn't defined.
Also, I've included the txt-file in the main text now. I don't know how I could forget such a crucial element to this exercise, and I think this might change the way I should solve this problem?

Comment: @Ajax1234 sooo confused right now. See Edit 4 in main text

Comment: @RicklePick the issue is that you are not returning anything in `read_data`.

Comment: @RicklePick just after `final_answer = {a:b[0] for a, b in answer.items()}`, add `return final_answer`

Comment: @Ajax1234 Still returns None :( Can I get you to write the whole completely correct for me please? I just can't get this to work no matter what I do

Comment: @Ajax1234 You are my hero. Thank you SO SO much!

Comment: @RicklePick glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Your file `"sequencing_reads.txt"` is in json format. You can use the json module in the python standard library to load your content into a dictionary quite easily.

```
import json

with open("sequencing_reads.txt") as f:
    sequence_dict = json.load(f)
```

Comment: @RicklePick Try reading the file into a string, then using `json.loads` to parse it into a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if your file is in json format and in separate lines, you should read it into a single line, maybe like this:

```
def read_data(file_name):
    lines = open(file_name).readlines()
    merged_line = " ".join([line.strip() for line in lines])
```

Secondly, The json.loads requires double quotes for the string(eg: {"a":"a"}). If you are using single quote(as in your example), there may be errors. So you can do like this:

```
# 1,use json.loads, but replace first
import json
merged_line = merged_line.replace("'", '"')
data = json.loads(merged_line)

# 2,use ast
import ast
data = ast.literal_eval(merged_line)
```